# How to center Header values in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I center the Header values in this code? Below is my code.

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt} % Default value: 6pt
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|c|m{4.2cm}|}
\hline
\bfseries{alt\_id} & \bfseries{retweet\_count} &
\bfseries{favorite\_count} & \bfseries{citation\_count} &
\multicolumn{1}{Sc|}{\bfseries comments} \\[2ex]
\hline
1301774 &3 &0 &7 &RT $@$infoism: The role of public libraries in c ...\\

1302862 &0 &0 &6 &Online access to higher education on YouTubeED...\\

2572404 &0 &1 &5 &The future of open access and library publishi... \\

2664241 &4 &0 &11 &RT $@$johnpoverington: Two ...\\

2664242 &4 &0 &1 &Two \#ChEMBL papers just out in J Cheminf http:...\\ 
[0.5ex] \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Twitter dataset used in our experiments.}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Can you please provide a Minimal working example MWE. Somthing that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that shows the problem your are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Your table will be too wide for standard paper size (letter or a4 paper). To be sure it fits within the margins, I suggest using the `tabularx` environment, only the last column being of type `X`,  and simply `c` for the remaining columns. Furthermore, this will simplify the code. Note that  your `\begingroup ... \endgroup` is unnecessary, since a table environment is already a group.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt} % Default value: 6pt
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|c|S{X}|}
\hline
alt\_id & retweet\_count &
favorite\_count & citation\_count &
\multicolumn{1}{Sc|}{\bfseries comments} \\[2ex]
\hline
1301774 &3 &0 &7 &RT $@$infoism: The role of public libraries in c ...\\

1302862 &0 &0 &6 &Online access to higher education on YouTubeED...\\

2572404 &0 &1 &5 &The future of open access and library publishi... \\

2664241 &4 &0 &11 &RT $@$johnpoverington: Two ...\\

2664242 &4 &0 &1 &Two \#ChEMBL papers just out in J Cheminf http:...\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Twitter dataset used in our experiments.}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I would also replace both instances of `$@$` with `@`, and I would replace `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}` with `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`. And, since you're setting the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\linewidth`, you can omit the remaining `\centering` instruction.

Comment: table is not in the center of the page. how to do this?

Comment: Normally it should, since there's a `\centering` command. Could you post a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I have update my code.

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE contains two versions of your table.

In the first version, I have removed all `\centering` commands and defined a new column `C` that is a horizontally centered variant of the `m` type that you used before. In order to horizontally center the title of the lat column, I have used the `\makecell[cc]{}` command from the `makecell` package. I have also removed the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands, as changes to lengths, widths and sizes that you make inside of a `table` environment are automatically only applied to this `table` environment. Lastly, I have also removed the `\\[2ex]` before the `\caption` command and replaced this by `\addtolength{\abovecaptionskip}{2ex}` and the corresponding `caption` package. However, please keep in mind that captions of tables are usually above the table while figure's captions are usually below them. Please also keep in mind that your table is quite wide and might not fit into the textwidth (as in the below MWE).

[image]

In order to overcome the last descibed issue, I have also included the second example table. In this, I have used a `tabularx` from the `tabularx` package in order to create a table that is automatically as wide as the textwidth. For the last column, I have used a modified (vertically centered, raggedright) version of the usual flexible width `X` type column. (As I have just seen now, this is quite similar to [Bernard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472095/134144))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\addtolength{\abovecaptionskip}{2ex}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


%%%%% Only needed for second table  %%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt}
   \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
  \rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}
  \begin{tabular}{|C{1.5cm}|C{2.6cm}| C{2.6cm}|C{2.6cm}|m{4.8cm}|}
    \hline
    alt\_id & retweet\_count & favorite\_count & citation\_count & \makecell[cc] {\textbf{comments}} \\[2ex]
    \hline
    1301774 & 3   & 0 & 7 & RT @infoism: The role of public libraries in c ...\\ 

    1302862 & 0   & 0   & 6 & Online access to higher education on YouTubeED...\\ 

    2572404 & 0  & 1  & 5 & The future of open access and library publishi... \\ 

    2664241 & 4 & 0 & 11 & RT @johnpoverington: Two ...\\ 

    2664242  & 4  & 0 & 1 & Two \#ChEMBL papers just out in J Cheminf http:...\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Twitter dataset used in our experiments.}
  \label{table:1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8.5pt} 
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}
  \rowcolors{1}{white}{mygray}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|X|}
    \hline
    alt\_id & retweet\_count & favorite\_count & citation\_count & \makecell[cc] {\textbf{comments}} \\[2ex]
    \hline
    1301774 & 3   & 0 & 7 & RT @infoism: The role of public libraries in c ...\\ 

    1302862 & 0   & 0   & 6 & Online access to higher education on YouTubeED...\\ 

    2572404 & 0  & 1  & 5 & The future of open access and library publishi... \\ 

    2664241 & 4 & 0 & 11 & RT @johnpoverington: Two ...\\ 

    2664242  & 4  & 0 & 1 & Two \#ChEMBL papers just out in J Cheminf http:...\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Twitter dataset used in our experiments.}
  \label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have used the first code. The problem is with the last column header its not align in the center